# R Markdown does not display result of sourced script

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm trying to create a DiagrammeR figure from a source file in R Markdown.

```
source("Gr01_-_QMOF.r", local = knitr::knit_global())
```

The contents of the file are:

```
library(DiagrammeR)
grViz("
digraph dot {

graph [layout = dot]

node [shape = rectangle,
      style = filled,
      color = '',
      height = 0.1,
      label = '',
      fontname = Helvetica,fontsize = 6]
edge [arrowsize = 0.1, arrowhead = none]

node [fillcolor = LightCoral]
a [label = 'My Mood']

node [fillcolor = DarkSeaGreen]
b [label = 'Relaxed']
c [label = 'Unrelaxed']

node [fillcolor = orange]

edge [color = grey]
a -> {b c}
}")
```

The file in question does run but does not produce the plot in the `rmd` file which is sourcing it.

How do I make it appear?

Answer (score 2):

A related issue and several options to fix that can be found at [`source` command in RMarkdown fails to render plot](https://community.rstudio.com/t/source-command-in-rmarkdown-fails-to-render-plot/47196).

As one option you could run your script via the code chunk option:

````
---
title: Source DiagrammeR
output: html_document
date: "2022-12-26"
---

```{r grviz, code = readLines('Gr01_-_QMOF.R'), echo=FALSE}
```
````

[image]

Comment: This didn't work for me for some reason but the suggestion in the link to store the grviz object in a variable and call that in the main script did.

Comment: Weird. Assigning to a variable was my first approach. (: But thought that the code chunk approach is more "elegant".